# Database (foreign key) issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I need to make a registration package for managing songs/CD's. My problem is that I need to link an artist to a track, but it's possible that it is a band or just an artist but I dont know how I would need to do this.

For now is have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZQLN.jpg

In a song there is a possibility to add a band or an artist or both. So bands exist of artists, thats why there is a table between them.

The problem that occurs now is that it is not possible to leave one of them blank because of the foreign keys, but I feel it is more than that and that im doing this the wrong way.

Someone that can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: I strongly recommend naming things using their proper name instead of these useless abbreviations. So `b_id` is a `band_id`, is it? What happens when you add a new entity called `Biographies`? Don't truncate names for the sake of typing. It's lazy and just makes your schema that much harder to digest.

Comment: Good tip, thanks. Working on it already.

Answer (score 1):

```
track
    id
    title

artist
    id
    name

band
    id
    name

artist_band
    artist_id
    band_id

artist_track
    artist_id
    track_id

band_track
    band_id
    track_id
```

Comment: This can works real nice. But can I make it some way that there at least has to be one artist or band coupled with a song?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `n_artist` and `n_band` as allowing `NULL`s. Foreign key constraints aren't checked when a column is `NULL`.

You can also, then, include a `CHECK` constraint. You can enforce that at least one of these columns isn't null. Or you can enforce that *exactly* one of the columns isn't null. Which one is correct depends on your domain. For Bands and Artists, I'd usually think of the second one being correct (i.e. I would define a track as being by a Band, or by an Artist. I'm not sure what interpretation should be imposed on a track associated with both)

```
CREATE TABLE T (
     /* Other Columns */
     BandID int null,
     ArtistID int null,
     /* Other constraints */
     constraint FK_Bands FOREIGN KEY (BandID) references Bands (ID),
     constraint FK_Artists FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) references Artists (ID),
     constraint CK_SingleAssociation CHECK (
          (BandID is null and ArtistID is not null) or
          (BandID is not null and ArtistID is null)
     )
)
```

Comment: I heard of this before, but I always though whats the idea behind a FK if it allows null?

Comment: @Gideon - I'm not sure what you're asking. But I'll take a guess. If you define a foreign key, *and* the referencing columns are defined as `not null`, then you must provide values in those columns that match the referenced table's key. But, if you allow `NULL`s, then no enforcement occurs (as it can't, if you accept the whole SQL concept of `NULL`s not being equal)